# Trouble filling sub-matches using C++11's std::regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I want to collect the Google Geolocation API's response:

```
{
  "location": {
   "lat": 37.42659,
   "lng": -122.07266190000001
  },
  "accuracy": 658.0
 }
```

I'm having difficulties to fill the sub-matches using `std::regex`:

```
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <regex>

  int main()
  {
     std::string json  = "{ \"location\": { \"lat\": 37.42659, \"lng\": -122.07266190000001 }, \"accuracy\": 658.0 }";
     std::string error = "error";

     if( json.find( "location" ) == std::string::npos ){
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
     }

     if( error.find( "location" ) == std::string::npos ){
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
     }

     try
     {
        std::regex pieces_regex("{ \"location\": { \"(lat)\": *([0-9.-]*),.*(lng)\": *([0-9.-]*).*(accuracy)\": *([0-9.-]*).*");
        std::smatch pieces_match;

        if (std::regex_match(json, pieces_match, pieces_regex)) {
           std::cout << json << '\n' << std::endl;
           for (size_t i = 0; i < pieces_match.size(); ++i) {
              std::ssub_match sub_match = pieces_match[i];
              std::string piece = sub_match.str();
              std::cout << "  submatch " << i << ": " << piece << '\n';
           }
        }
     }
     catch( std::regex_error &e )
     {
        std::cout << "ERRor: " << e.what() << std::endl;
     }

     return 0;

  }
```

Obs.: in g++ compile with `--std=c++11` or higher

Using VIM's regex I can fit all sub-matches like a charm:

```
/{ "location": { "\(lat\)": *\([0-9.-]*\),.*\(lng\)": *\([0-9.-]*\).*\(accuracy\)": *\([0-9.-]*\).*
```

And works fine!

using above pattern on a `:substitute` command:

```
.s/{ "location": { "\(lat\)": *\([0-9.-]*\),.*\(lng\)": *\([0-9.-]*\).*\(accuracy\)": *\([0-9.-]*\).*/\1:\2 \3:\4 \5:\6/g
```

Comment: You shouldn't use regexes to parse JSON

Comment: it's only a adhoc situation and I don't want to add a dependency to the software.

Comment: @RodrigoGurgel: Right, because a header-only library like RapidJSON would be such a huge burden...

Comment: You need to escape opening braces in the regular expression, as in `std::regex pieces_regex("\\{ \"location\": \\{...");` With that, [your code appears to work](http://rextester.com/JBCSYB46967)

Comment: @NicolBolas didn't know RapidJSON, I'll try to use it before the sprint ends. Thanks.

Comment: I know the pain of not allowing common-sense libraries (or anything external, if possible) in a project due to "reasons from above" that make no sense.  My sympathies.  I agree with the suggestion of RapidJSON though.  Anything header-only is often easier to persuade to be allowed to include.  Worked for me and RapidXML in fact!

Comment: @KevinAnderson and I'll have also to read the license. It's really boring but I acknowledge the company's worries. But, as Steve Jobs said: "the cheapest code is the one that you don't write" (something like this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented parsing JSON with regex is not the best idea. Nevertheless, a working regular expression looks like this:

```
std::regex pieces_regex("\\{ \"location\": \\{ \"(lat)\": *([0-9.-]*),.*\"(lng)\": *([0-9.-]*).*\"(accuracy)\": *([0-9.-]*).*");
```

Comment: So I basically forgot to escape `{`

Comment: And quotation marks in front of "lng" and "accuracy". But it would actually work without them too, because there is a catch-all `.*`.

Comment: ERROR: regex_error
the expression contains mismatched square brackets ('[' and ']') ###

Maybe the .- and the end [0-9.-]

Comment: It works for me. Any chance you are using g++ 4.8? It had some bugs related to [] in regex.